# How to remove \vskip from beginning of multicols-environment

Tags: spacing, lists, multicol

In the documentation of the `multicol` it reads that as a first action of an `multicols` environment (if there's enough space etc.) “[…] a `\vskip` of `\multicolsep` is added.”

I use `enumitem` and combine it with `multicol` by:

```
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols}
}
```

to get two-columned list environments. Now I really dislike the `\vskip` the package puts at the beginning of an environment. How can I remove it (just for the lists)?

Comment: Did you try adding `\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}` after `\raggedcolumns` in that code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `\setlength{\multcolsep}{0pt}` to the `before` code; this won't propagate to other `multicols` environments in the document, because it's issued in a group (the `enumerate` or `itemize` environment).

However, removing it will leave *no* space around the list, so maybe it's better to say

```
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\setlength{\multicolsep}{\topsep}\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols}
}
```

and the space around

```
\begin{enumerate}[twocol]
...
\end{enumerate}
```

will be the same as the space around an `enumerate` environment without the new option.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. But somehow I end up having lesser vertical space (no space?) around the list than normally (even with your fix!). I'm tired for today, so I'll look into it tomorrow and report back what I found.

Comment: @K.Stm. a list environment like enumerate uses \topsep when it is being part of a paragraph. However if it s a paragraph on its own (i.e., preceded by a blank line) it is actually using \topsep +\partopsep so perhaps that explains why you see less space than expected.

Comment: @egreg. What is the benefit of `raggedcolumns`? And what is the difference if we omit it?

Comment: @SayOL It was in the OP's code. No benefit and no damage either: just a stylistic decision