# Two columns; Space before left alignment; placement of QED symbol

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, two-column, multicol, amsart

I have used the code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78561/how-to-remove-vskip-from-beginning-of-multicols-environment) to remove the vertical space before multicols. I want to left-align some equations. I have two issues:

1. The equations are not lined up on the left with the line preceding the solution (it's hard to tell from the picture, but there is a very small horizontal space on the left side of the aligned environment).
2. How can I make the QED symbol align with the bottom-most row in the solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}

% multi columns in enumerate
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
    before=\raggedcolumns\setlength{\multicolsep}{\topsep}\begin{multicols}{2},
    after=\end{multicols}
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

Here is a problem.
\begin{enumerate}[twocol]
\item $\mathbf{a} = \langle 1, 2 \rangle$, $\mathbf{b} = \langle 3, 4 \rangle$
\columnbreak
\item $\mathbf{a} = \langle 1, 2 \rangle$, $\mathbf{b} = \langle 3, 4 \rangle$
\end{enumerate}
\begin{proof}[Solution]\hfill
\begin{enumerate}[twocol]
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = (1)(3)+(2)(4) = 11 \\
&|\mathbf{a}| = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5} \\
&|\mathbf{b}| = \sqrt{3^2+4^2} = 5
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = (1)(3)+(2)(4) = 11 \\
&|\mathbf{a}| = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5}
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\qedhere\end{proof}

Issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item The $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}$, $|\mathbf{a}|$, $|\mathbf{b}|$ in the solution are not left-aligned with the $\mathbf{a}$ the precedes the solution (there's a very small horizontal space).
\item The $\square$ needs to align with the lowest row in the solution.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason I am using aligned (rather than simply writing \\ to make new lines, each with an equation) is because I might change my mind and align all the equations at the equal sign, rather than on the left side. But still, doing this would leave a small horizontal space to the left of the aligned environment.

Comment: no time to test just now, but if you put `\qedhere` just before the `\end{enumerate}` that should do it, or at least it would if it were one column; never tried it with `[twocolumn]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two variants of how to do it, which are very similar for the placement of the `qed` symbol, with `\qedhere` preceded by a negative  vertical space just before the end-of-proof. The second variant uses the `tasks` environment, which is done for ‘horizontal’ numbering. I took the opportunity to define a variable-sized `\abs` macro with the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools` (see details for its use in the documentation of mathtools).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[1]), label-width=1.5em}

% multi columns in enumerate
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
    before=\raggedcolumns\setlength{\multicolsep}{\topsep}\begin{multicols}{2},
    after=\end{multicols}
}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

Here is a problem.
\begin{enumerate}[twocol]
\item $\mathbf{a} = \langle 1, 2 \rangle$, $\mathbf{b} = \langle 3, 4 \rangle$
\columnbreak
\item $\mathbf{a} = \langle 1, 2 \rangle$, $\mathbf{b} = \langle 3, 4 \rangle$
\end{enumerate}
\begin{proof}[Solution]\hfill
\begin{enumerate}[twocol]
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = (1)(3)+(2)(4) = 11 \\
&\abs[\big]{\mathbf{a}} = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5} \\
&\abs{\mathbf{b}} = \sqrt{3^2+4^2} = 5
\end{aligned}$
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = (1)(3)+(2)(4) = 11 \\
&|\mathbf{a}| = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5}\
\end{aligned}$%
\end{enumerate}
\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}\qedhere
\end{proof}

Issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item The $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}$, $|\mathbf{a}|$, $|\mathbf{b}|$ in the solution are not left-aligned with the $\mathbf{a}$ the precedes the solution (there's a very small horizontal space).
\item The $\square$ needs to align with the lowest row in the solution.
\end{itemize}
\vspace{1cm}

Here is a problem.
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\mathbf{a} = \langle 1, 2 \rangle$, $\mathbf{b} = \langle 3, 4 \rangle$
\task $\mathbf{a} = \langle 1, 2 \rangle$, $\mathbf{b} = \langle 3, 4 \rangle$
\end{tasks}
\begin{proof}[Solution]\hfill
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = (1)(3)+(2)(4) = 11 \\
&\abs{\mathbf{a}} = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5} \\
&\abs{\mathbf{b}} = \sqrt{3^2+4^2} = 5
\end{aligned}$
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
&\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = (1)(3)+(2)(4) = 11 \\
&|\mathbf{a}| = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5}\\
\end{aligned}$%\vspace{1ex}\par
%\qedhere
\end{tasks}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip }\qedhere
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After checking your solution, things did not improve. I gave a MWE, but perhaps in my main file (where I have additional packages) there is something causing your solution to not work properly. The aligned environments are still very slightly to the right of where they should be in order to align with each $\mathbf{a}$ in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @Nunya: In my code (alone) `\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b` is exactly aligned with the corresponding element in the statement of the problem. The absolute  values do have a difference of `0.9pt` to the right, and I think this is due to the side-bearings of the vertical rule. If you have more than that, it is probably due either to a package which I don't load, or to a personal macro. To eliminate it, you should from a file with the same preamble and just this code, comment the lines in the preamble which are not necessary to compile, and uncomment them progressively until the problem appear again.

Comment: Will do. I will accept your answer, since it does answer the MWE I posted. Hopefully I can find the issue when introducing more packages. Thank you again!